# Why is socket file descriptor argument incremented by one when calling select?

Tags: c, sockets

Whenever I see a `select` call in C, I see it written as:

```
select(sock_fd + 1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &tv)
```

or something similar. What is the meaning behind incrementing the file descriptor?

Comment: select's first argument is the highest socket descriptor (plus one) in the fdset's.  Here's a snippit from its man page: "nfds should be set to the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1."

Comment: What would the argument be if there are no file descriptors in any of the sets? What if the highest file descriptor was '0'?

Comment: If there is no desriptor in any of the sets, why should anyone call `select` at all? If the highest is 0, it will obviously be 1.

Comment: @Gerhardh Because you might have a general event loop that also uses the timeout for some things. It would be silly to have a special case for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [POSIX specification of `select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html):

> The `nfds` argument specifies the range of descriptors to be tested. The first `nfds` descriptors shall be checked in each set; that is, the descriptors from zero through `nfds-1` in the descriptor sets shall be examined.

That is, you give the *size* of the set, where each descriptor is an *index*.

Descriptors sets are basically implemented as arrays, and `sock_fd` (in your case) is an *index* into that array, while `sock_fd + 1` is the *size* of the array to check.